# What does dual wielding do, without the Dual Wielding talent?

Tags: torchlight

In Torchlight you can wield any two one-handed weapons.  There is a Dual Wielding talent that adds damage when wielding two weapons, but what happens when dual wielding without the talent?  Does it simply alternate back and forth?  If the weapons are exactly the same, is there any DPS benefit?  How does it work with one melee and one ranged weapon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only effect of the dual wielding talent in Torchlight is to increase the damage done while dual wielding - the act of using a weapon in each hand, itself, is unrelated.

If you have two melee weapons, you will alternate back and forth on your attacks. If you have a melee weapon and a ranged weapon, you will only swap to the melee weapon if you are within range, otherwise you will exclusively use the ranged weapon.

Comment: Do you simply alternate, so there is no benefit besides more variety or shared benefits from one weapons?

Comment: @C.Ross some abilities require dual-wielding. It may also, slightly, increase attack speed (as it does in Dibalo II) but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @C.Ross Dual-wielding simply alternates attacks but special effects on either weapon apply to both.  For example if you dual wield 1 sword with hp steal and 1 with mana steal, both weapons should steal both hp and life.  Basically the point of dual wielding is to get extra enchants and bonus damage from the dual wielding skill.  It doesn't improve DPS in any other way as the weapons simply alternate.